# How do I make an autocomplete with $http?

Tags: angularjs

I have a search field on an edit page where the user should enter which category a product belongs to. There is a large amount of categories and the search should use $http POST or GET to get the search results.

When searching online I find a bunch of different solutions, but being a AngularJS beginner I find it very hard to decide which way to go.

The functionality I want:

- Search using $http POST or GET
- Possibility to use keyboard to select a search result
- A simple and straight forward solution. Preferably without adding an external library to my app

**HTML:**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="category" id="category" ng-model="formData.category" placeholder="Search..." required>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of Directive already build with good code quality, tested & support 
so you can choose one from this site [angular module](http://ngmodules.org/)

and there is also module for auto-complete which match your task
[ngAutocomplete](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngAutocomplete)

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you Typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead)

more info here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a good option, so I'll probably accept this answer. However, I run into some problems. I started a new thread for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670987/ui-bootstrap-typeahead-not-returning-async-values