# UI Bootstrap Typeahead not returning async values

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to do an autocomplete search using UI Bootstrap Typeahead to select a category from a database.

I have set up an example database with 4 categories, the final one will contain more than a thousand categories.

When I start typing, the search results return 4 rows (so something must be working, because I tried to change the number of rows in the DB and the search result mirrors the total number of rows) but with no value. However, it doesn't matter what I write so it doesn't seem to be matching.

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="asyncSelected" typeahead="name for name in getCdOnCat($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" required>
```

**controller.js**

```
//Typeahead: Category Search
$scope.getCdOnCat = function (searchVal) {
    return dataFactory.getCdOnCategory(searchVal, globalVal_accessToken, globalVal_storeId).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.categories);
        return response.data.categories;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: dataFactory.getCdOnCategory');
    });
};
```

**service.js**

```
app.factory("dataFactory", function ($http) {
var factory = {};

factory.getCdOnCategory = function (searchVal, accessToken, storeId) {
    return $http.get('data/getCdOnCategory.aspx?searchVal=' + searchVal + '&accessToken=' + accessToken + '&storeId=' + storeId)
};

return factory;
});
```

**JSON**

```
{ "categories":[ 
    { "name": "Clothes" }, 
    { "name": "Cypress" }, 
    { "name": "Citrus" }, 
    { "name": "Cats" } 
] }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/F4n1kNOHfZ9f3Zz63x2P?p=preview

change

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="category" id="category" 
 placeholder="Search..." ng-model="asyncSelected" 
 typeahead="name for name in getCdOnCat($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
 required>
```

to

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="category" id="category" 
 placeholder="Search..." ng-model="asyncSelected" 
 typeahead="obj.name for obj in getCdOnCat($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
 required>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Getting closer. Now the values are shown, and the letters matching the search a bold. But I only want it to show rows that match the search (also want to be able to limit this number when I will have more than a thousand rows), right now all rows are shown no matter what I write. It would also be good with a row "No categories matching..." if no rows match.

Comment: @peta you shpold to that on your servers side. I've shows you onlny basic example and I can do server side filtration on pluker. But your code seems to be fine, you passing query value to you server so your server should response with array matching categories

Comment: You are of course right! But what about when there are no results?

Comment: @peta you can return from you server ie ["No results"]

Comment: Yes, but won't this option be selectable then?

Comment: @peta you can handle that inside your controller please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/yaWIvcux6faNskJzQ8yZ?p=preview

Comment: excellent. thanks! ran into a new problem. If validation message ("this field is required.") is loaded on an unsuccessfull submit the search results of the categories jumps away and is misplaced. Any solution for that?

Comment: Updated your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zFmjw5SMXMoHmdMZt9ma . However, I can't initiate the validation from the library that I am using for this app. I have included the library files. Can't see why that is (you probably can :)) To see an example of what the validation looks like: https://tictail.com/developers/documentation/uikit/#Form_Validation

Comment: Also realized that it is possible to save the form without selecting an option if I just hit submit. How can I know that it has selected a valid option? Sorry for running two different questions at the same time :)

Comment: Thanks! it doesn't really work though. for some reason it doesn't behave exactly as locally, so I set up a new plunkr (based on an old one I had for a similar setup) where you can see exactly how the validation behaves. The form is in the file help.html and HelpController in script.js. Appreciate your help! http://plnkr.co/edit/LRSGXqxjtbYcr6rjTj69

Comment: Now two new threads. One for each question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820293/ui-bootstrap-typeahead-make-input-invalid-if-no-option-is-selected + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26816277/tyepahead-search-results-misplaced-with-validation