# Tyepahead search results misplaced with validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using a validation plug-in based on jQuery validation in my AngularJS app (which is built on top of a jQuery library).

When I use ui bootstrap Typeahead with validation the search results are misplaced.

**Plunkr:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYP58GxITghkTqE7PNHy

**HTML (help.html)**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category "{{formData.category}}"</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="formData.category" typeahead="obj.name for obj in getCdOnCat($viewValue)" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" required>
    </div>
```

**JS (script.js) - HelpController**

```
//Typeahead: Category Search
    $scope.getCdOnCat = function (searchVal) {
        return dataFactory.getCdOnCategory(searchVal).then(function (response) {
            return response.data.categories;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Error: dataFactory.getCdOnCategory');
        });
    };

    $scope.$watch('formData.category', function (value) {
        if (value === "No matching categories") {
            $scope.formData.category = "";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you simplify that splunk? I don't even see where the typeahead is. Note that ui-bootstrap is in beta and there are new fixes and new bugs every week...

Comment: @Sulthan Cleaned up the plunk. The Typehead code is in the HelpController.